# Omit Leptonica Library from Tesseract

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, tesseract, leptonica

Working on an OCR project, I am trying to figure out if there is any way or possibility to omit Leptonica Library from Tesseract and maybe replace it with OpenCV.
Already have OpenCV on the C layer and planning to combine that with Tesseract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible (unless you rewrite tesseract).

But you can compile leptonica with the minimal dependencies (zlib + png).

Also I would suggest to check your OpenCV package as it includes support for [tesseract OCR](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/ddc/classcv_1_1text_1_1OCRTesseract.html).

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple languages for tesseract/tessdata simultaneously when using it through OpenCV C++.